# mcustomscrollbar Cannot read property 'tagName'

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

```
mCustomScrollbar 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
com.yandex.bar.chrome.js:1 b
com.yandex.bar.chrome.js:1 a
```

I tested this in Chrome on the Joomla rt-anacron template v1.3.

- jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js v3.0.8
- HTML5 Shiv 3.7.3-pre
- jquery.mousewheel.min.js v 3.1.12
- [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js)
- headroom_init.js
- latest JUI

I think this code causes the conflict:

```
(function($){ 
  $(window).load(function(){  
  $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
    mouseWheelPixels: 300,
    scrollButtons:{ enable:true }, theme:"minimal"}); 
}); })(jQuery);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Assuming `tagName` is a property of mCustomScrollbar, have you initialised mCustomScrollbar first?

Comment: The console's of the different browser developer tools normally also provide the script name and line and column number. Is `com.yandex.bar.chrome.js:1` the script where the error occurred? Then this seems rather related to that Yandex script than to mCustomScrollbar.

Comment: body {position: absolute !important;top: 50px !important;left: 0 !important;bottom: 0 !important;right: 0 !important;overflow-y: auto !important;overflow-x: hidden !important;}html {overflow: hidden !important;}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('body').mCustomScrollbar();
});

this code works perfect without errors , but now dynamic Auto-Hide Header  http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js  works as STATIC..

Help please how to fix it  - headroom.js - header not moving anymore

Comment: solution found, need change tagname for mcustomscrollbar on html, body or other .. eg #customdivid or other tag name. because this tags #idnames conflict with headroom.js